# What is reason for javax.net.debug value not to be modified at runtime?

Tags: java, debugging

The flag `javax.net.debug` is read at the beginning of any java application, and can't be modified during runtime, as explained in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47504797/2685234.

However, I'm not sure why is it designed in such a way that we cannot modify this flag without bringing down a running java application. For example, with a java server in production, it would have helped to identify some SSL or any other such issues just by enabling this flag, without need to bring down the server application itself.

There could be a strong reason why it is designed in this way. Could somebody please throw some light.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be inefficient to always check whether the debug flag is on or not, considering that in 99.99999% of the cases it's one or the other at all times.

Comment: It is because it is only read once, for performance reasons.

Comment: Surely the obvious reason is security? Or, perhaps because object construction may be based on this flag, and changing it won't cause those objects to be recreated. Or one of the many other problems with mutable global state.

Comment: @Kayaman, @EJP debug flag is a variable in `SSLSocketFactory.java` class, which is read each time before logging. And java need not keep on polling for this value, it can modify the debug flag whenever there is an invocation of `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "any-value")` in the runtime. If that is the only place where this value is read, i don't see it having any impact on performance. But there seems to be something hiding from my eyes!

Comment: Continued... And, to avoid polling for this value, there could have been many ways, like enabling setting of the system property within code (as in above comment - so that coders can play with it), or providing a handle via jmx, or anything that can be thought of. But designers of this piece of code did not go that way.

Comment: Well you do notice that it's doing a privileged action? That's expensive and you can't do it another way if you want to keep the SecurityManager in charge. So reading it once at startup is the effective way to handle it.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks. That's a nice point which I did not pay much attention to.